# How to query SQL server function using sort order

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a select statement that gives different results when querying same function from 2 databases but with same information. See below:

```
use DB1
SELECT * FROM fn_transaction('','',null)
```

results:

```
ALBGU = 24.20,ALFGU = 4.00,DABGU = 24.20,JPBGU = 8.80,MDFGU = 4.00,RSBGU = 13.20,SMFGU = 4.00,SRBGU = 17.60

use DB2
SELECT * FROM fn_transaction('','',null)
```

results:

```
ALFGU = 4.00,MDFGU = 4.00,SMFGU = 4.00,JPBGU = 8.80,RSBGU = 13.20,SRBGU = 17.60,ALBGU = 24.20,DABGU = 24.20
```

As you can see the results from DB1 starts with ALBGU = 24.20......then ends with SRBGU = 17.60

and results from DB2 Starts with ALFGU = 4.00 ........ then ends with DABGU = 24.20

I have tried to use the following queries but no luck:

```
use DB1
SELECT * FROM fn_transaction('','',null) order by column1

use DB2
SELECT * FROM fn_transaction('','',null) order by column1
```

please: column1 contains the information am referring to

Anyone who knows how to make the results set the same? Please help

here is the function:

```
/****** Object:  UserDefinedFunction [dbo].[fn_Transactions_BatchTransactions]    Script Date: 2017-06-23 11:26:58 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER FUNCTION 
/*SVN TAG: 90868*/
 [dbo].[fn_Transactions_BatchTransactions]
(
    @xlist_ClientPortfolios    xml,     -- Xml list of type and id which must be included in the list  <objectlist><object type="ClientPortfolio" id="1" code="ABC" grouping="0"/></objectlist> Must support ClientPortfolio, Composite, ClientPortfolioClassification, CodeLookup grouping determines whether the objects resulting from the resolution of a group type to individual client portfolios must be grouped null XML string = All Client Portfolios null Instrument list string = All Instruments
    @DateFrom    datetime,     -- The starting date in a date range
    @DateTo    datetime,     -- The ending date in a date range
    @DateType    varchar(50),     -- Which date to filter on - Trade/Value/Created/ExpectedSettlement/FinalSettlement/Confirmed/Reconciled - default = trade date
    @BatchStatus  varchar(10)   -- The status of the batch
)
RETURNS @Results TABLE
(
    BatchId int,
    PortfolioTransactionId int,
    ClientPortfolioId int,
    ClientPortfolioCode varchar(120),
    ClientPortfolioName varchar(120),
    InstrumentId int,
    InstrumentCode varchar(120),
    InstrumentName varchar(100),
    TransactionBaseTypeCode varchar(100),
    TransactionDescriptorCode varchar(100),
    DescriptorName varchar(100), 
    ExchangeRate_InstrumentToBase TFundamentalDecimal,
    Nominal TFundamentalDecimal,
    EffectOnNominal TFundamentalDecimal,
    TradePrice TFundamentalDecimal,
    TradeYield TFundamentalDecimal,
    Consideration TFundamentalDecimal,
    TradeDate datetime,
    ExpectedSettlementDate datetime,
    PortfolioValuationDate datetime,
    BrokerId int,
    Brokerage TFundamentalDecimal,
    BrokerageRateAsPercentage TFundamentalDecimal,
    CreatedOn datetime,
    CreatedBy int,
    ManagerAllocation varchar(max),
    InstrumentClassCode varchar(100),
    BatchStatus varchar(10),
    YieldDate datetime
)
AS
BEGIN
-- If the DateTo parameter does not have a time portion specified, make it 3 millseconds before midnight
-- 3 milliseconds since SQL <=2005 stores datetimes to a precision of 1/300th of a second
if right(convert(varchar, @DateTo, 113), len('00:00:00:000')) = '00:00:00:000'
begin
    set @DateTo = convert(varchar, @DateTo, 106) + ' 23:59:59.997'
end
declare
    @Param_xlist_ClientPortfolios    xml,     -- Xml list of type and id which must be included in the list  <objectlist><object type="ClientPortfolio" id="1" code="ABC" grouping="0"/></objectlist> Must support ClientPortfolio, Composite, ClientPortfolioClassification, CodeLookup grouping determines whether the objects resulting from the resolution of a group type to individual client portfolios must be grouped null XML string = All Client Portfolios null Instrument list string = All Instruments
    @Param_DateFrom    datetime,     -- The starting date in a date range
    @Param_DateTo    datetime,     -- The ending date in a date range
    @Param_DateType    varchar(50)     -- Which date to filter on - Trade/Value/Created/ExpectedSettlement/FinalSettlement/Confirmed/Reconciled - default = trade date
select
    @Param_xlist_ClientPortfolios = @xlist_ClientPortfolios,
    @Param_DateFrom=@DateFrom,
    @Param_DateTo=@DateTo,
    @Param_DateType=@DateType   
declare @Objects table
(
    ClientPortfolioId int, -- The ClientId
    ClientPortfolioBaseCurrencyCode    varchar(15), -- The currency code of the client portfolio    
    ObjectGrouping bit, --Whether grouping should be applied
    GroupObjectType    varchar(35),     -- The type of object e.g. ClientPortfolio, Composite etc.
    GroupObjectId    int,     -- The ClientPortfolioId if ClientPortfolio type, CompositeId (PortfolioStructureId) if Composite type etc.
    GroupObjectCode    varchar(100),     -- Code of the object
    GroupObjectDescription    varchar(200),     -- Description of the object
    ResolvedObjectList xml  -- The XML that has already been resolved by a run through the object resolver datasource
primary key (ClientPortfolioId,GroupObjectType, GroupObjectId)
)
insert into @Objects
    (ClientPortfolioId,ClientPortfolioBaseCurrencyCode, 
     ObjectGrouping, GroupObjectType, GroupObjectId, GroupObjectCode, GroupObjectDescription)
select distinct
    ClientPortfolioId, ClientPortfolioBaseCurrencyCode, 
    ObjectGrouping, GroupObjectType, GroupObjectId, GroupObjectCode, GroupObjectDescription
from dbo.fn_ClientPortfolios_ObjectResolver(@Param_xlist_ClientPortfolios, @Param_DateTo, 0) r
declare @rules table
(
    DateType varchar(50),
    DateAsAt datetime,
    AccountingRulesetId int
Primary Key
(
    DateAsAt ,
    AccountingRulesetId 
))
insert into @rules
    (DateType, DateAsAt, AccountingRulesetId)
select distinct
    ar.Holdings, ar.HoldingsDateAsAt, ar.AccountingRulesetId
from @Objects cp
inner join Clients c on c.ClientId = cp.ClientPortfolioId
inner join fn_ClientPortfolios_AccountingRules(null) ar on ar.AccountingRulesetId = c.AccountingRulesetId
if isnull(@Param_DateType, '') != '' and @Param_DateType != 'Use_Accounting_Rule'
begin
  select @Param_DateType = upper(@Param_DateType)
  update @rules set DateType = @Param_DateType
end
;with transactions as (
select 
        ptbt.BatchTransactionID,
        c.ClientId,
        c.AccountCode,
        c.CompanyName
from 
PortfolioTransactionBatchTransactions ptbt
join portfolios p on ptbt.PortfolioAccountId = p.PortfolioID
join clients c on p.ClientID = c.ClientID
inner join @rules rules 
    on rules.AccountingRulesetId = c.AccountingRulesetId
    and rules.DateAsAt = (SELECT MAX(DateAsAt) 
                            FROM @rules ar2 
                            WHERE DateAsAt <= ptbt.TransactionDate 
                            AND rules.AccountingRulesetId = ar2.AccountingRulesetId)
inner join @Objects o on o.ClientPortfolioId = c.ClientId
where rules.DateType = 'TRADE' and ptbt.TransactionDate between @DateFrom and @DateTo
union
select 
        ptbt.BatchTransactionID,
        c.ClientId,
        c.AccountCode,
        c.CompanyName
from 
PortfolioTransactionBatchTransactions ptbt
join portfolios p on ptbt.PortfolioAccountId = p.PortfolioID
join clients c on p.ClientID = c.ClientID
inner join @rules rules 
    on rules.AccountingRulesetId = c.AccountingRulesetId
    and rules.DateAsAt = (SELECT MAX(DateAsAt) 
                            FROM @rules ar2 
                            WHERE DateAsAt <= ptbt.TransactionDate 
                            AND rules.AccountingRulesetId = ar2.AccountingRulesetId)
inner join @Objects o on o.ClientPortfolioId = c.ClientId
where rules.DateType = 'VALUE' and ptbt.PortfolioValuationDate between @DateFrom and @DateTo
union
select 
        ptbt.BatchTransactionID,
        c.ClientId,
        c.AccountCode,
        c.CompanyName
from 
PortfolioTransactionBatchTransactions ptbt
join portfolios p on ptbt.PortfolioAccountId = p.PortfolioID
join clients c on p.ClientID = c.ClientID
inner join @rules rules 
    on rules.AccountingRulesetId = c.AccountingRulesetId
    and rules.DateAsAt = (SELECT MAX(DateAsAt) 
                            FROM @rules ar2 
                            WHERE DateAsAt <= ptbt.TransactionDate 
                            AND rules.AccountingRulesetId = ar2.AccountingRulesetId)
inner join @Objects o on o.ClientPortfolioId = c.ClientId
where rules.DateType = 'EXPECTEDSETTLEMENT' and ptbt.ExpectedSettlementDate between @DateFrom and @DateTo
union
select 
        ptbt.BatchTransactionID,
        c.ClientId,
        c.AccountCode,
        c.CompanyName
from 
PortfolioTransactionBatchTransactions ptbt
join portfolios p on ptbt.PortfolioAccountId = p.PortfolioID
join clients c on p.ClientID = c.ClientID
inner join @rules rules 
    on rules.AccountingRulesetId = c.AccountingRulesetId
    and rules.DateAsAt = (SELECT MAX(DateAsAt) 
                            FROM @rules ar2 
                            WHERE DateAsAt <= ptbt.TransactionDate 
                            AND rules.AccountingRulesetId = ar2.AccountingRulesetId)
inner join @Objects o on o.ClientPortfolioId = c.ClientId
inner join PortfolioTransactionBatches ptb on ptb.BatchID = ptbt.BatchID and ptb.CreatedOn between @DateFrom and @DateTo and rules.DateType = 'CREATED'
) 
insert into @results
select  ptbt.BatchId,
        ptbt.PortfolioTransactionId,
        transactions.ClientId,
        transactions.AccountCode,
        transactions.CompanyName,
        i.InstrumentId,
        i.InstrumentCode,
        i.InstrumentName,
        ptd.PortfolioTransactionBaseType,
        ptd.DescriptorCode,
        ptd.DescriptorName,
        ptbt.CurrencyExchangeRateToBase,
        ptbt.Nominal,
        ptbt.RequestedUnits*ptbase.SettlementEffectOnInstrument as EffectOnNominal,
        ptbt.Price,
        ptbt.Yield,
        ptbt.Consideration,
        ptbt.TransactionDate,
        ptbt.ExpectedSettlementDate,
        ptbt.PortfolioValuationDate,
        ptbt.BrokerId, 
        ptbt.Brokerage,
        case when (ptbt.Price*ptbt.Nominal)=0 then 0
            when ptbt.Brokerage=0 then 0
            else round((ptbt.Brokerage/(ptbt.Price*ptbt.Nominal))*100, 3)
        end as BrokerageRatePercentage,
        ptb.CreatedOn,
        ptb.CreatedOnUserId,
        '',
        i.InstrumentClassCode   ,
        ptb.BatchStatus,
        ptb.YieldDate
from portfolioTransactionBatchTransactions ptbt 
join transactions on ptbt.BatchTransactionID = transactions.BatchTransactionID
join PortfolioTransactionBatches ptb on ptb.BatchId = ptbt.BatchID and (isnull(@BatchStatus,'') = '' or ptb.BatchStatus = @BatchStatus)
join instruments i WITH(NOEXPAND) 
  on i.instrumentID = ptbt.InstrumentID
inner join PortfolioTransactionDescriptors ptd with (nolock) on ptd.DescriptorCode=ptbt.PortfolioTransactionType
inner join PortfolioTransactionBaseTypes ptbase with (nolock) on ptbase.PortfolioTransactionBaseType=ptd.PortfolioTransactionBaseType
--Extra insert to deal with transafers and the TOCLIENTID (Trac 14366)
insert into @results
select  ptb.BatchId,
        PortfolioTransactionId,
        c.ClientId,
        AccountCode,
        CompanyName,
        i.InstrumentId,
        InstrumentCode,
        InstrumentName,
        ptd.PortfolioTransactionBaseType,
        DescriptorCode,
        DescriptorName,
        CurrencyExchangeRateToBase,
        Nominal,
        ptbt.RequestedUnits * ptbase.EffectOnInstrument * ptbase.AffectsUnits as EffectOnNominal,
        Price,
        Yield,
        Consideration,
        ptbt.TransactionDate,
        ExpectedSettlementDate,
        PortfolioValuationDate,
        BrokerId, 
        Brokerage,
        case when (ptbt.Price*ptbt.Nominal)=0 then 0
            when ptbt.Brokerage=0 then 0
            else round((ptbt.Brokerage/(ptbt.Price*ptbt.Nominal))*100, 3)
        end as BrokerageRatePercentage,
        ptb.CreatedOn,
        ptb.CreatedOnUserId,
        '',
        InstrumentClassCode ,
        BatchStatus,
        YieldDate   
from PortfolioTransactionBatches ptb
inner join PortfolioTransactionBatchTransactions ptbt on ptbt.BatchId = ptb.BatchId
inner join Instruments i WITH(NOEXPAND) 
 on i.InstrumentId = ptbt.InstrumentId
left join Portfolios p with (nolock) on p.PortfolioId = ptbt.PortfolioAccountId
inner join Clients c with (nolock) on c.ClientId = ptb.ClientPortfolioToId and p.ClientId <> c.ClientId
inner join @Objects o on o.ClientPortfolioId = c.ClientId
inner join PortfolioTransactionDescriptors ptd with (nolock) on ptd.DescriptorCode=ptbt.PortfolioTransactionType
inner join PortfolioTransactionBaseTypes ptbase with (nolock) on ptbase.PortfolioTransactionBaseType=ptd.PortfolioTransactionBaseType
inner join @rules rules 
    on rules.AccountingRulesetId = c.AccountingRulesetId
    and rules.DateAsAt = (SELECT MAX(DateAsAt) 
                            FROM @rules ar2 
                            WHERE DateAsAt <= ptbt.TransactionDate 
                            AND rules.AccountingRulesetId = ar2.AccountingRulesetId)
where 
(
   (rules.DateType = 'TRADE' and ptbt.TransactionDate between @DateFrom and @DateTo)
or (rules.DateType = 'VALUE' and ptbt.PortfolioValuationDate between @DateFrom and @DateTo)
or (rules.DateType = 'CREATED' and ptb.CreatedOn between @DateFrom and @DateTo)
or (rules.DateType = 'EXPECTEDSETTLEMENT' and ptbt.ExpectedSettlementDate between @DateFrom and @DateTo)
or (@DateFrom is null and @DateTo is null)
)
and (isnull(@BatchStatus,'') = '' or BatchStatus = @BatchStatus)
--Work out the manager allocations
declare @PortfolioTransactionBatchAllocations table
(
    PortfolioTransactionId int,
    AllocationSummary varchar(1000) default('')   
);
declare @PortfolioTransactionBatchAllocationsOpen table
(
    BatchId int,
    ClientPortfolioId int,
    InstrumentId int,
    AllocationSummary varchar(1000) default('')   
);
with Percentages(thisId)
as
(select distinct PortfolioTransactionId from @Results)
insert into @PortfolioTransactionBatchAllocations(PortfolioTransactionId, AllocationSummary)
select thisId,(
    select distinct stuff( (select c.AccountCode + ' = ' + convert(varchar, cast(alloc.Percentage as decimal(5,2))) + ','
    from @Results ptids   
    inner join BatchTransactionAllocations bta on ptids.PortfolioTransactionId = bta.BatchTransactionId
    inner join PortfolioTransactionBatchAllocations alloc on bta.BatchAllocationId = alloc.BatchAllocationId
    inner join Clients c on alloc.ClientPortfolioId = c.ClientId         
    where ptids.PortfolioTransactionId = thisid for xml path('')), 1, 0, '') as AllocationSummary)
from Percentages;
declare @CompositeData table
    (
        Date datetime,
        ClientGroupId int,
        ManagerGroupId int,
        ManagedCompositeId int
    )
    declare @Data table
    (
        ClientPortfolioId int,
        InstrumentClassCode varchar(100),
        Date datetime,
        ClientGroupId int,
        ManagerGroupId int,
        ManagedCompositeId int
    )
    declare GetComposites cursor forward_only
    for
        select c.ClassificationId
        from Classification c
        join ClassificationType t on c.ClassificationTypeID = t.ClassificationTypeId
        where t.ClassificationTypeCode = 'MAN-CO'
    declare @CompositeId int
    declare @EffectiveDate datetime
    set @EffectiveDate = getdate()
    open GetComposites
    fetch next from GetComposites into @CompositeId
    while(@@fetch_status <> -1)
    begin
            insert into @CompositeData(ManagedCompositeId, ClientGroupId, Date)
            select @CompositeId, cg.ClassificationId, @EffectiveDate 
            from Classification cg
            join ClassificationType ct on cg.ClassificationTypeID = ct.ClassificationTypeId and ct.ClassificationTypeCode = 'PO-CMAN'
            join (select EntityId from fn_Classifications_EntityList_I(@CompositeId, '', @EffectiveDate)) t on cg.ClassificationId = t.EntityId             
            update @CompositeData
            set ManagerGroupId = s.ClassificationId
            from
                (select mg.ClassificationId 
                from Classification mg
                join ClassificationType ct on mg.ClassificationTypeID = ct.ClassificationTypeId and ct.ClassificationTypeCode = 'PO-MAN'
                join (select EntityId from fn_Classifications_EntityList_I(@CompositeId, '', @EffectiveDate)) t on mg.ClassificationId = t.EntityId) s
            where ManagedCompositeId = @CompositeId             
        fetch next from GetComposites into @CompositeId
    end 
    close GetComposites
    deallocate GetComposites
    insert into @Data(ClientPortfolioId, ManagedCompositeId, ManagerGroupId, ClientGroupId, Date, InstrumentClassCode)
    select t.EntityId, cd.ManagedCompositeId, cd.ManagerGroupId, cd.ClientGroupId, cd.Date, mci.InstrumentClassCode
    from @CompositeData cd
    cross apply dbo.fn_Classifications_EntityList_I(cd.ClientGroupId, '', cd.Date) t
    left join ManagedCompositeInstruments mci on cd.ManagedCompositeId = mci.ManagedCompositeId;
with PercentagesOpen(thisBatchId, thisClientPortfolioId, thisInstrumentId)
as
(select distinct BatchId, ClientPortfolioId, InstrumentId from @Results where PortfoliotransactionId = 0)
insert into @PortfolioTransactionBatchAllocationsOpen(BatchId, ClientPortfolioId, InstrumentId, AllocationSummary)
select thisBatchId, thisClientPortfolioId, thisInstrumentId,
(
    select stuff( (select c.AccountCode + ' = ' + convert(varchar, cast(c.Percentage as decimal(5,2))) + ','
    from (select distinct c.AccountCode, ptba.Percentage
    from @Results ptids   
    inner join PortfolioTransactionBatches ptb on ptids.BatchId = ptb.BatchId
    inner join portfoliotransactionbatchallocations ptba
      on ptb.BatchId = ptba.BatchId and ptba.InstrumentId = ptids.InstrumentId
    inner join @Data d on d.ClientPortfolioId = ptids.ClientPortfolioId
        and d.ManagerGroupId = ptba.ClientGroupClassificationId 
    inner join instruments i WITH(NOEXPAND) 
  on i.InstrumentId = ptids.InstrumentId
        and i.InstrumentClassCode = d.InstrumentClassCode
    inner join Clients c on ptba.ClientPortfolioId = c.ClientId    
    where ptids.BatchId = thisBatchId and ptids.ClientPortfolioId = thisClientPortfolioId and ptids.InstrumentId = thisInstrumentId ) c   
    for xml path('')), 1, 0, '') as AllocationSummary
)
from PercentagesOpen;
update @PortfolioTransactionBatchAllocations set AllocationSummary = left(AllocationSummary, len(AllocationSummary) - 1)
update @PortfolioTransactionBatchAllocationsOpen set AllocationSummary = left(AllocationSummary, len(AllocationSummary) - 1)
update @results
set ManagerAllocation = AllocationSummary
from @results r
inner join @PortfolioTransactionBatchAllocations alloc on alloc.PortfolioTransactionId = r.PortfolioTransactionId
where r.PortfolioTransactionId <> 0 and alloc.AllocationSummary is not null
update @results
set ManagerAllocation = AllocationSummary
from @results r
inner join @PortfolioTransactionBatchAllocationsOpen alloc 
    on alloc.BatchId = r.BatchId and alloc.ClientPortfolioId = r.ClientPortfolioId and alloc.InstrumentId = r.InstrumentId
where r.PortfolioTransactionId = 0 and alloc.AllocationSummary is not null
return
END
```

Comment: So what's wrong with the results of the statements with the `order by`?

Comment: I have an App that picks up differences between 2 databases, so even using order by the results are still different. As long as the app picks up any difference, it has to be fixed. I have spent countless hours trying to fix this but no luck. @NicoVanBelle fn_transaction is a db function. am using sql server 2012

Comment: Function is present in both the database. Show the function code. What if the underlying data present in two database is different..

Comment: So the fn_transaction function generates a delimited string? Shouldn't you look at the code of that function then to make it's result ordered in the way you want?  If you're looking for an answer from here, then you should at least include that function to the question.

Comment: The code has hundreds of lines, hopefully it helps?

Comment: I have added the code and column1 refers to managerallocation column

Comment: Why you are expecting to return same result after running in two different database? What if the data present in underlying tables are different

Comment: @Prdp, The data is the same, I have restored the same db but with different names, so if you query these 2 databases, you get different results. Its weird, spend countless hours but could not figure out this

Comment: Are you the only `user` in those two database ?

Comment: @Prdp am the only user here

Comment: @Immortal - Take all the underlying tables from both the database and  use `EXCEPT` to compare the data.. I suspect the data is changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm aware that this might not be the answer but is worth trying it. If it doesn't work let me know and I remove this answer. I didn't put it on a comment because is too long.

It seems that there is an issue with the use of the Stuff function on AllocationSummary (which ends up being assigned to managerallocation). It is apparently doing nothing but looking at the order puzzle it seems that is doing something worse than nothing:

Stuff(x,1,0,’’) only adds an '' string at the beginning of the string which might be causing some erratic behaviour on the ordering. Please remove the stuff function wrapping allocationSummary and give it a try.

This is the bit of code I refer to:

```
(
    select stuff( (select c.AccountCode + ' = ' + convert(varchar, cast(c.Percentage as decimal(5,2))) + ','
    from (select distinct c.AccountCode, ptba.Percentage
    from @Results ptids   
    inner join PortfolioTransactionBatches ptb on ptids.BatchId = ptb.BatchId
    inner join portfoliotransactionbatchallocations ptba
      on ptb.BatchId = ptba.BatchId and ptba.InstrumentId = ptids.InstrumentId
    inner join @Data d on d.ClientPortfolioId = ptids.ClientPortfolioId
        and d.ManagerGroupId = ptba.ClientGroupClassificationId 
    inner join instruments i WITH(NOEXPAND) 
  on i.InstrumentId = ptids.InstrumentId
        and i.InstrumentClassCode = d.InstrumentClassCode
    inner join Clients c on ptba.ClientPortfolioId = c.ClientId    
    where ptids.BatchId = thisBatchId and ptids.ClientPortfolioId = thisClientPortfolioId and ptids.InstrumentId = thisInstrumentId ) c   
    for xml path('')), 1, 0, '') as AllocationSummary
)
from PercentagesOpen;
update @PortfolioTransactionBatchAllocations set AllocationSummary = left(AllocationSummary, len(AllocationSummary) - 1)
update @PortfolioTransactionBatchAllocationsOpen set AllocationSummary = left(AllocationSummary, len(AllocationSummary) - 1)
update @results
set ManagerAllocation = AllocationSummary
from @results r
inner join @PortfolioTransactionBatchAllocations alloc on alloc.PortfolioTransactionId = r.PortfolioTransactionId
where r.PortfolioTransactionId <> 0 and alloc.AllocationSummary is not null
update @results
set ManagerAllocation = AllocationSummary
```

and this:

```
select thisId,(
    select distinct stuff( (select c.AccountCode + ' = ' + convert(varchar, cast(alloc.Percentage as decimal(5,2))) + ','
    from @Results ptids   
    inner join BatchTransactionAllocations bta on ptids.PortfolioTransactionId = bta.BatchTransactionId
    inner join PortfolioTransactionBatchAllocations alloc on bta.BatchAllocationId = alloc.BatchAllocationId
    inner join Clients c on alloc.ClientPortfolioId = c.ClientId         
    where ptids.PortfolioTransactionId = thisid for xml path('')), 1, 0, '') as AllocationSummary)
```